# How can we hit/run the rules using code

Tags: 7, rules

I have defined a rule in " **Configuration » Workflow » Rules**". 
I have setup this as following...

**EVENT** : After saving a new account
**Conditions** : User has role(s) 
             And role is (Referral Source) 
    enter code here
**Actions**  Send a HTML mail.

But it's not sending the mail to register user. It's because of the user don't have the role as **Referral Source** at the same time. I am assigning the role using the PHP code and I would like to run the rule on same time. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create first rule "**After saving a new user account**" action "**Add user role**" to user and set its priority first(by set its **weight** 0 in **SETTINGS** of rule) and create one another rule for the same and set condition for role is(Reffereal source) and action send a HTML mail, set its priority down (by set its **weight** 1 in **SETTINGS** of rule) will work for you.

Comment: But I am not assigning role(Referral Source) using the rules. I am assigning new user role with the hlep of PHP code.

Comment: I thinks no need to work on php all works with rules.